# Generate a PDF file from partial view using Knp Snappy

Tags: php, symfony, pdf-generation, wkhtmltopdf, snappy

I want to generate a pdf file from a partial view twig which extends an other view.
this is how I generate the PDF from the partial view:

```
public function generatePdfAction(Request $request)
{
   //initialize $employee

    $html = $this->renderView('PFEEmployeesBundle:Employee:view.html.twig',
        array('employee'=> $employee)
    );

    return new Response(
        $this->get('knp_snappy.pdf')->getOutputFromHtml($html,array(
            "id"=>"bloc"
        )),
        200,
        array(
            'Content-Type'          => 'application/pdf',
            'Content-Disposition'   => 'attachment; filename="file.pdf"'
        )
    );
}
```

It gives me this error:

> The option 'id' does not exist.

Comment: Why you passing 'id' option to getOutputFromHtml()? Probably you should call this method without $options param. "$this->get('knp_snappy.pdf')->getOutputFromHtml($html),"

Comment: I was just trying to get a div block tegged with id.